# How can I copy a whole folder to a certain IP adress with powershell?

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am currently trying to implement a functionality (preferably in powershell), which would regularily (every hour) copy a certain folder from my desktop computer to another computer.

The other computer is not listed in my local network, but I do have the IP, as well as the credentials of an user with the necessary username and password.

So far, I tried to use robocopy, but I can't quite seem to figure out how to get it to work.

If it matters: My desktop computer is running Windows 10, while the other computer is a raspberry pi running on Raspbian.

Is there any example code available of already successful attempts at doing this?

Comment: What protocol are you wanting to use for the copy? The code for uploading to FTP will be different to copying to a SMB Share...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`robocopy` doesn't handle authentication. If you need to provide credentials for accessing a remote (SMB) share you need to map it to a drive letter before you can use it with `robocopy`. That is assuming your RasPi is running Samba.

```
net use X: \\192.168.23.42\share /user:username password
robocopy C:\some\folder X:\ /s
net use X: /d
```

The above code runs in CMD as well as in PowerShell.

You can also map network drives via `New-PSDrive`, but that requires a bit more code:

```
$pw   = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ('username', $pw)
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\192.168.23.42\share' -Credential $cred -Persist | Out-Null
robocopy C:\some\folder X:\ /s
Remove-PSDrive -Name X
```

---

If your credentials are not for SMB but for SSH access you could use the [WinSCP .Net assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

Comment: That looks very promising! I will give this a try as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

If ssh is enabled on your raspberry (which is normally the case) you could use `WinScp`. WinScp offers a bunch of command line options and scripting check the [WinScp website](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#console). You can create your own WinScp copy script and start it via:

`winscp.com /script=script.txt`

Hope that helps.

[enter link description here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#console)